# Pandas DataFrame.resample() and anchoring DateTimeIndex timestamps to an origin

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If one does Pandas `DataFrame.resample()` for a DateTimeIndex, how can one set the offset for time frequencies like "30 days" which is different from "business month start/business month end" or "start of a quarter of an hour".

For example, how can one ensure all time frequencies are calculated from the UNIX epoch and not from an arbitrary date like the first timestamp in the data? As otherwise `pd.Timestamp.floor()` may later give values that do not match values in the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor `DateTimeIndex` with `resample(origin=...)` parameter:

For example, if you want to create continuous resamples of minimum values of each 30 days period and make sure all values are forward filled:

```py
# 30D (30 days) is different from M (business month) freqstr
resampled_df = grouped_df.resample("30D, origin="epoch").agg({"value":"min"}).ffill()
```

This way, you always know there is value in your `DataFrame` no matter what timestamp you use to query the index, and the indexing does not fail because offsetting issues:

```py
import pandas as pd
timestamp = pd.Timestamp("2020-09-02")
timestamp.floor("30D")
```

This will give you

```
Timestamp('2020-08-06 00:00:00')
```

... which is the value in `DateTimeIndex` and always aligned to the UNIX epoch origin.